# Restricting system resources to .NET application

Tags: .net

I am maintaining a managed Windows Service project which basically invoke/run the (managed) jobs (IJob implementations from different sub-teams) at scheduled time. There are few jobs which occasionally stall the system resources.

While waiting for my sub-teams to debug/fix their jobs, is there any way that I can somehow control in my parent executor before it happens…for instance starting multiple AppDomains and then somehow restricting system resources (CPU, memory, number of managed threads the job can spawn etc) allowed to each AppDomain? Can Windows Activation Service (Windows 2008) help if we host the jobs as WCF and invoke them through WAS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/Setting_Max_Memory_Limit.aspx) on CodeProject which shows how you could restrict the memory used by a given process.